# How to add a react component in Drupal 8 for node listing with pagination

Tags: reactjs, drupal-8

I have a blog built in Drupal8 with more than 10K articles. I would like to implement the article listing and pagination in ReactJS. How can I do this ?

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49511618

Answer (score 1):

First you should understand difference between, SPA (single-page application) and MPA (multi-page application).

Drupal generates pages in the back-end and sends to user (browser). ReactJS is a library to make SPA, which different from Drupal. You can use React with MPA, but it's a bit tricky.

You can use [jsonapi](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi) get the data from Drupal.